# Overriding Doorkeeper refresh token response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I am trying to also send the user details in the refresh token response using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) (I am using it on API only). I tried calling the `Doorkeeper::TokensController#create` method in one of my other controllers, but it does not work. As a workaround, I created a new controller that inherits from `Doorkeeper::TokensController` and in the create method I try to do `render json: { tokens: JSON.parse(super), user: the_instance_i_want }`, but this would do render twice, as [this method](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/main/app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb) also has a render.

Is there any other way to solve this? I would also want to refresh the user data when refreshing the token.

Answer (score 1):

You should render the same response for first jwt issue and refresh's. Anyway you can override `TokenResponse` `body` method:

```
module Doorkeeper
  module OAuth
    class TokenResponse
      def body
        {
          "access_token" => token.plaintext_token,
          "token_type" => token.token_type,
          "expires_in" => token.expires_in_seconds,
          "refresh_token" => token.plaintext_refresh_token,
          "scope" => token.scopes_string,
          "created_at" => token.created_at.to_i,
          "CUSTOM1" => YOUR_IMPLEMENTATION,
          # custom
          response_code: I18n.t('custom.status_code.ok'),
          response_message: I18n.t('custom.success.default')
        }.reject { |_, value| value.blank? }
      end
    end
  end
end
```